# PHP - AJAX and MySQL select filter xmlhttp.open not loading jquery datatables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, datatables

Using this example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp
I have set up a table echoing from database.

I am now trying to initiate datatables plugin on the table, everything is set up correctly but it wont work. I have tried to initiate the datatable in the html and the php pages but neither seem to work.

I am similarly having the same problem incorporating this example:
http://davidwalsh.name/animated-ajax-jquery

Is it this bit from the first example causing the issue as the page has already loaded before xmlhttp.open and xmlhttp.send(); is sent.

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?username="+username+"&year="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

**head**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: 'jquery-record-delete.php',
          data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
          beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
          },
          success: function() {
            parent.slideUp(300,function() {
              parent.remove();
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });

        jQuery( function( $ ) {// Implements the dataTables plugin on the HTML table
var $adtTable= $("#academic_days_table").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 30,       
        "sDom": '<"clear">t>',
        "aaSortingFixed": [[0,'asc']],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false }
            ]
});

    });
```

**HTML page**

```
 function showUser(str, username)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("department_logs_txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("department_logs_txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?username="+username+"&year="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 } 

<form>
    <select id="employee_user">
    <option value="">--</option>  
</select>

<select id="they" onchange="showUser(this.value, employee_user.value)">
<option value="">--</option>

    </select>
</form>
```

**php page**

```
<?php
include_once("scripts/connection.php");

$year = $_GET["year"];
$username = $_GET["username"];

$is_academic_result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM holiday_entitlement_academic WHERE employee = \'' . $username . '\' AND academic_year = \'' . $year . '\' ');

if($is_academic = mysql_fetch_array($is_academic_result)) {

echo'<div style="float:left; width:400px;">';

echo'<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
<td>'.$is_academic['employee'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Entitlement:</strong></td>
<td>'.$is_academic['entitlement'].' '.$is_academic['units'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Department / Division:</strong></td>
<td>'.$is_academic['division'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Line Manager:</strong></td>
<td>'.$is_academic['line_manager'].'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
echo'<br/>';

echo'</div>';


echo'<table class="dataTable" id="academic_days_table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<thead>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>End Date</th>
<th>'.$is_academic['units'].' to be taken</th>
<th>'.$is_academic['units'].' remaining</th>
<th></th>
</thead>';

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>-</td>';
echo '<td>-</td>';
echo '<td>-</td>';
echo '<td>'.$is_academic['entitlement'].'</td>';
echo '<td></td>';

echo '</tr>';


$input = $is_academic['entitlement'];
}

else {echo 'You currently dont have a record for this academic year. ';}


//$requests_result = mysql_query('
//SELECT * 
//FROM holiday_entitlement_business_manual
//LEFT JOIN requests ON holiday_entitlement_business_manual.employee = requests.employee
//WHERE employee = \'' . $username . '\' AND academic_year = \'' . $acyear . '\' ');


$requests_result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM requests WHERE employee = \'' . $username . '\' AND approved = 1 AND academic_year = \'' . $year . '\' ORDER BY start_date ASC');

$remainder = 0;

while($requests = mysql_fetch_array($requests_result)) {

$remainder = ($remainder == 0) ? $input : $remainder;
$out = $remainder - $requests['days'];
if($out < 0){
      break;
}
$remainder = $out;


echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$requests['start_date'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$requests['end_date'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$requests['days'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$remainder.'</td>';
echo'<td><a href="?delete='.$requests['id'].'" class="delete"><img src="images/cross.png"></a></td>';
echo'</tr>';
}

echo'</table>';

?>
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Please, avoid tutorials from W3schools (at least for the php part). You have far better tutorials elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: the bit in the head part is not working (the datatable is not getting initiated and the ajax delete is not working). Its like the scripts are not even being loaded. I thought it may be because the page had already been loaded before the xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?username="+username+"&year="+str,true); was called from the select menu. Where would i include the $('a.delete').click(function(e) {} and var $adtTable= $("#academic_days_table").dataTable();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include the script in xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()

Datatables is now loaded and $('a.delete').click(function(e) {} is working

Here is an example:

```
 function showUser(str, username)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("department_logs_txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {           
     document.getElementById("department_logs_txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     $('#business_days_table').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 30,       
        "sDom": '<"clear">t>',
        "aaSortingFixed": [[0,'asc']],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false }
            ]
     });    
     $('#academic_days_table').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 30,       
        "sDom": '<"clear">t>',
        "aaSortingFixed": [[0,'asc']],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": false }
            ]
     });
  $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'getuser.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
      beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      },
      success: function() {
        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
          parent.remove();
        });
      }
    });
  });

     }
   }

 xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?username="+username+"&year="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```